Error initializing Firebase Admin in onRequest using Cloud Functions v2 defined secrets and strings
Hi I am upgrading my firebase cloud function from first generation to the second generation; with callable function I  can initialize the firebase app with no issues, with onRequest function, with the same code I get this error on the firebase's  log:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'INTERNAL')
    at initializeApp (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/firebase-namespace.js:246:21)
    at instantiateFirebase

;
this is the code for initializing firebase:
    const privateKey= defineSecret("PRIVATE_KEY");
    const clientEmail = defineString("CLIENT_EMAIL");
    const projectId = defineString("PROJECT_ID");
    const databaseURL = defineString("DATABASE_URL");
    initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert({
        privateKey: privateKey.value().replace(/\\n/g, "\n"),
        projectId: projectId.value(),
        clientEmail: clientEmail.value(),
      }),
      databaseURL: databaseURL.value(),
    });

it should be ok, indeed it works with my callable functions, but it does not with my onRequest function: this is an express server, I googled around but I had no luck, is it some detail in the firebase cloud functions or node/express that does not let inizializing the firebase app?
this is the code of index.ts:
<!--language:typescript -->
import {getAuth} from "firebase-admin/auth";
import {CloudUser} from "./models/cloudUser";
import express = require("express");
import cors = require("cors");
import {setCurve, getCurve, postSettings,
  getSettings, listSettings} from "./settings/settings";
import {authorizationsList} from "./authorizations/authorizationsList";
import {addAuthorization} from "./authorizations/addAuthorization";
import {fetchUser} from "./users/users";
import {canUseProject} from "./authorizations/canUseProject";
import {watchdog4CacheV2} from "./utilityFunctions/watchdog4Cache";
import {onSchedule} from "firebase-functions/v2/scheduler";
import {onCall, onRequest} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import {listUserByEnabledFunction} from
  "./users/listUserbyEnabledFunction";
import {instantiateFirebase} from "./configs/firebase";
import {defineSecret, defineString} from "firebase-functions/params";
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());


app.use(cors({
  origin: [
    "http://localhost:8100",
    "https://testinsole.designo.cc",
    "https://digitalaid.thinkingadditive.com",
    "https://testinsole.designo.cc/",
    "null",
    "https://preprod.designo.cc",
  ],
  credentials: true,
  exposedHeaders: "Location",
}));

let resources = [
  {id: 1, name: "sample data one"},
  {id: 2, name: "sample data two"},
  {id: 3, name: "sample data three"},
];

app.post("/settings/lastCurve", setCurve);
app.get("/settings/lastCurve", getCurve);
app.get("/users/fetch", fetchUser);
app.post("/settings", postSettings);
app.get("/settings/:settingsKey", getSettings);
app.get("/settings/keys/list", listSettings);
app.get("/testFeature/:featureKey", async (req, res)=>{
  const db = instantiateFirebase().db;
  const token:string = req.get("x-jwt")?.split("Bearer ")[1] as string;
  const featureKey = req.params.featureKey as string;
  // res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  let uid ="";
  try {
    uid = (await (getAuth().verifyIdToken(token?token:""))).uid;
    const userDoc = db.collection("users").doc(uid);


    const user = new CloudUser(((await userDoc.get()).data())).setKey(uid);
    res.status(200)
        .send(user.hasFunctionEnabled(featureKey));
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send("il token non va "+err);
  }
});
app.get("/authorizations/list", authorizationsList);
app.post("/authorizations/add", addAuthorization);
app.get("/authorizations/canuseproject", canUseProject);
app.get("/api/resource", (req:any, res:any) => {
  res.json(resources);
});
app.get("/api/resource/:id", (req:any, res:any) => {
  const id = parseInt(req.params.id);
  const resource = resources.find((r) => r.id === id);

  if (resource) {
    res.json(resource);
  } else {
    res.status(404).json({message: "Resource not found"});
  }
});
app.post("/api/resource", (req:any, res:any) => {
  const {id, name} = req.body;
  const newResource = {id, name};
  resources.push(newResource);
  res.status(201).json(newResource);
});
app.put("/api/resource/:id", (req:any, res:any) => {
  const id = parseInt(req.params.id);
  const updatedResource = req.body;

  resources = resources.map((r) => {
    if (r.id === id) {
      return {...r, ...updatedResource};
    } else {
      return r;
    }
  });

  res.json(updatedResource);
});
app.delete("/api/resource/:id", (req:any, res:any) => {
  const id = parseInt(req.params.id);
  resources = resources.filter((r) => r.id !== id);
  res.status(204).end();
});
const clientEmail = defineString("CLIENT_EMAIL");
const projectId = defineString("PROJECT_ID");
// exports.api2 = functions.https.onRequest(app);
// every day at 00:01 remove old entries
exports.watchdog4CacheV2 = onSchedule("1 0 * * *", watchdog4CacheV2);
const privateKey= defineSecret("PRIVATE_KEY");
const databaseURL = defineString("DATABASE_URL");
const params ={CLIENT_EMAIL: clientEmail, PROJECTID: projectId,
  DATABASE_URL: databaseURL};
exports.apiV2 = onRequest({secrets: [privateKey], ...params}, app);
exports.listUserByEnabledFunction=
  onCall({secrets: [privateKey], ...params}, listUserByEnabledFunction);


exports.addCustomClaim = onCall({secrets: [privateKey], ...params},
    async (data) => {
      const admin = instantiateFirebase().admin;
      const user = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.data.email);
      console.log("adding claims ", data.data.claims, "to", user.uid);
      try {
        await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, data.data.claims);
        if (data.data.logoutUser) {
          console.log("logging out user", user.uid);
          await admin.auth().revokeRefreshTokens(user.uid);
        }
        return await {
          message: ` Success!claims ${Object.keys(data.data.claim)}
        have been set on ${data.data.email}`,
        };
      } catch (err) {
        return {error: err, user: user.uid};
      }
    });

this is the code of listUserByEnabledFunction:
import {instantiateFirebase} from "../configs/firebase";
import {CloudUser} from "../models/cloudUser";

// import {collection} from "firebase/firestore";
const listUserByEnabledFunctionOnCall = async (data:any)=>{
  const db = instantiateFirebase().db;
  const usersData = await db.collection("users").get();
  const users = usersData.docs.map((u)=>{
    return new CloudUser(u.data()).setKey(u.id);
  });
  return users.filter((user)=>{
    return user.
        hasFunctionEnabled(data.data["functionKey"]);
  });
};
export {listUserByEnabledFunctionOnCall as listUserByEnabledFunction};

this is instantiateFirebase:
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import {defineSecret, defineString} from "firebase-functions/params";
import {initializeApp} from "firebase-admin";
const instantiateFirebase = ()=>{
  console.log("instantiating fb");
  const privateKey= defineSecret("PRIVATE_KEY");
  const clientEmail = defineString("CLIENT_EMAIL");
  const projectId = defineString("PROJECT_ID");
  const databaseURL = defineString("DATABASE_URL");
  console.log(`project id ${projectId.value()}`);
  initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
      privateKey: privateKey.value().replace(/\\n/g, "\n"),
      projectId: projectId.value(),
      clientEmail: clientEmail.value(),
    }),
    databaseURL: databaseURL.value(),
  });
  console.log("done");
  const db = admin.firestore();
  const realtime = admin.database();
  return {db, admin, realtime};
};
export {instantiateFirebase};

I call initializeApp  from instantiateFirebase, firebase app is initialized correctly by the callable function like listUserByEnabledFunction, but it is not initialized correctly by function on request attached to the end point of express like authorizationslist:
import {getAuth} from "firebase-admin/auth";
import {CloudUser} from "../models/cloudUser";
import {CloudAuthorization} from "../models/cloudAuthorization";
import {RealTimeCache} from "../utilityFunctions/realTimeCache";
import {paginate} from "../utilityFunctions/paginate";
import {instantiateFirebase} from "../configs/firebase";
const authorizationsList = async (req: any, res: any) => {
  const token: string = req.get("x-jwt")?.split("Bearer ")[1] as string;
  let uid = "";
  let userKey = "";
  console.log("getting authorization's list", new Date());
  const {page, limit}= req.query;
  // res.status(200).send({"message": `page:${page},limit:${limitDocuments}`});
  const pageNumber =page? Number(page): 0;
  const pageSize = limit? Number(limit):5;
  const db = instantiateFirebase().db;
  try {
    uid = (await (getAuth().verifyIdToken(token ?
       token : "token indefinito"))).uid;
    const userDoc = db.collection("users").doc(uid);
    const user = new CloudUser(((await userDoc.get()).data())).setKey(uid);
    // ifUserkey is undefined it looks for the authorizations of the loggedUser
    if ( !user.hasFunctionEnabled("Sq8gJkvGKrDoTpoc4DLb")&&
    req.query.userKey &&req.query.userKey!=user.key) {
      res
          .status(500)
          .send(`the user ${user.email} is not enabled to get the
       authorizations of ${req.query.userKey}`);
    }
    const mapAuthorizations2Id = (auth:CloudAuthorization)=>{
      return auth._id;
    };
    userKey = user.hasFunctionEnabled("Sq8gJkvGKrDoTpoc4DLb")&&
    req.query.userKey?req.query.userKey: user.key;
    const cache = new RealTimeCache();
    cache.getEntry(userKey).then((data)=>{
      res.status(200).send({data: paginate(data.data, pageSize, pageNumber),
        totalCount:
        data.data.length, hasMore: data.data.length > pageNumber*pageSize});
    }).catch(async (err)=>{ // entry  missing or expired
      console.log("errore", err);
      const query = db.
          collection("authorizations").
          where("userKey", "==", userKey);
      const rawAuthorizations = await query.get();
      console.log("raw authorizations", rawAuthorizations.docs.length);
      const authorizations = rawAuthorizations.
          docs.
          map((a:any) => new CloudAuthorization(a.data()).setKey(a.id));
      console.log("authorizations", authorizations.length);
      res.status(200).
          send({data: paginate(authorizations.map(mapAuthorizations2Id),
              pageSize, pageNumber),
          totalCount: authorizations.length, hasMore:
        authorizations.length>pageNumber*pageSize});
      cache.setEntry(userKey, authorizations.map(mapAuthorizations2Id));
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send("qualcosa non va  nel cloud " + err);
  }
};

export {authorizationsList};
const authorizationsListV2 = async (req: any, res: any) => {
  const token: string = req.get("x-jwt")?.split("Bearer ")[1] as string;
  let uid = "";
  let userKey = "";
  console.log("getting authorization's list V2", new Date());
  const {page, limit}= req.query;
  // res.status(200).send({"message": `page:${page},limit:${limitDocuments}`});
  const pageNumber =page? Number(page): 0;
  const db = instantiateFirebase().db;
  const pageSize = limit? Number(limit):5;
  try {
    uid = (await (getAuth().verifyIdToken(token ?
       token : "token indefinito"))).uid;
    const userDoc = db.collection("users").doc(uid);
    const user = new CloudUser(((await userDoc.get()).data())).setKey(uid);
    // ifUserkey is undefined it looks for the authorizations of the loggedUser
    if ( !user.hasFunctionEnabled("Sq8gJkvGKrDoTpoc4DLb")&&
    req.query.userKey &&req.query.userKey!=user.key) {
      res
          .status(500)
          .send(`the user ${user.email} is not enabled to get the
       authorizations of ${req.query.userKey}`);
    }
    const mapAuthorizations2Id = (auth:CloudAuthorization)=>{
      return auth._id;
    };
    userKey = user.hasFunctionEnabled("Sq8gJkvGKrDoTpoc4DLb")&&
    req.query.userKey?req.query.userKey: user.key;
    const cache = new RealTimeCache();
    cache.getEntry(userKey).then((data)=>{
      res.status(200).send({data: paginate(data.data, pageSize, pageNumber),
        totalCount:
        data.data.length, hasMore: data.data.length > pageNumber*pageSize});
    }).catch(async (err)=>{ // entry  missing or expired
      console.log("errore", err);
      const db = instantiateFirebase().db;
      const query = db.
          collection("authorizations").
          where("userKey", "==", userKey);
      const rawAuthorizations = await query.get();
      console.log("raw authorizations", rawAuthorizations.docs.length);
      const authorizations = rawAuthorizations.
          docs.
          map((a) => new CloudAuthorization(a.data()).setKey(a.id));
      console.log("authorizations", authorizations.length);
      res.status(200).
          send({data: paginate(authorizations.map(mapAuthorizations2Id),
              pageSize, pageNumber),
          totalCount: authorizations.length, hasMore:
        authorizations.length>pageNumber*pageSize});
      cache.setEntry(userKey, authorizations.map(mapAuthorizations2Id));
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send("qualcosa non va  nel cloud " + err);
  }
};

export {authorizationsListV2};


It would help if you show the complete, minimal code for both functions so we can see what's different between them and ideally copy and run them for ourselves.  Please edit the question to share these details.  I can assure you this has nothing to do with express on its own terms, but we need to see the context in which this code actually runs.

I suggest also adding some logging to see if your string parameters contain the values you expect.

yes thanks I checked this, they are correct

I don't see where you are calling initializeApp in the code of your onRequest function in index.ts.  I see defineString and defineSecret, but they're not being used.  The only use of initializeApp I see in within instantiateFirebase, which is only used with your callable function.  Please make sure each code sample is complete.

FYI, code is really hard to read without proper indentation.  You can use markdown code fences to delimit code and simply paste the properly formatted code inside the fences without having to change it at all.  Please update it so it's easier to follow.

I have noticed that importing initializeApp from firebase-admin/app  fixes this problem, but become impossible to validate the token

That sounds like a different problem, which you will want to post separately.

using initializeApp from firebase-admin/app it works
